# What happens when you move to not an rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, c++11

So I've been burned by this a couple of times. What is the difference between this:

```
 Movable&& object = std::move(another_movable);
```

and this:

```
 Movable object = std::move(another_movable);
```

It seems like both should work equally, but I always get inexplicable behavior (properties of the object changing) with the second example. Why is this?

Comment: One creates a reference, the other instantiates an object.

Comment: So the first calls the move constructor, and the second calls move assignment?

Comment: No, the first doesn't call anything, just like an lvalue reference, and the second calls the move constructor.

Comment: @sircodesalot: No, the first is an alias, the second call the move constructor (if available).

Comment: If you have a problem with the *second* example, you are doing something really wrong. Start learning move-semantics from scratch. (And with the above question, there is no real advice as it does not contain enough information)

Comment: The *second* one uses the move constructor, *if* there is one (otherwise it uses the copy constructor, if there is one). The first one just creates a reference. No new object is created.

Comment: @juanchopanza: or copy constructor, if move-ctor is not accessible

Comment: @DanielFrey, turns out my move constructor was wrong. But now I at least understand why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe comparing it to an lvalue-reference version might help:

```
Object& object = another_object;

Object object  = another_object;
```

The first is a reference to an lvalue, so no constructors are called. It just *refers* to the object named `another_object`, like a pointer. `Object object` creates a brand new object so the constructors will be called (not assuming copy-elision).

Now rvalue-references are the same, but they are tailored exclusively for rvalues. They now *refer* to the rvalue from which it is initialized.

Answer (score 5):

```
Movable&& object = std::move(another_movable);
```

This makes another reference to the same object as `another_movable`.

```
Movable object = std::move(another_movable);
```

This makes a new object initialized from an rvalue of `another_movable`.

Answer (score 0):

as was already said, first is copying a reference. as with all pointer-types you really shouldn't have return-type being an rvalue unless it's on the heap.

however, 2nd is a bit more complicated than just being an rvalue initialization. consider:

```
Moveable object = another_moveable;
```

or

```
Moveable object = function_returning_another_moveable();
```

seemingly the latter is initialization from a true, non-casted rvalue. but see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

and the former actually depends on what constructors Moveable has.

as for unexpected behaviour, this is most likely because of inheritance-loss, so to say. i.e. if another_moveable is only derived from Moveable, Moveable will use rvalue initialization for the Moveable parent of another_moveable only, and whatever data the derived object had is now lost.

just for emphasis: Moveable having an rvalue initialization doesn't mean the other object is merely getting a new reference, rvalue initialization is for data stored on the heap to stay where it was, with only pointers and references in the new objects being copied over from old. rvalue initialization still does copy the whole object, but afterwards it makes sure that when the old object is destroyed, its data on the heap will stay, and this should be done by changing the old object's pointers! the compiler doesn't actually do any of that, the program and the headers used must make sure the expected things are done!